# Error when trying to log into ESPN Masher API

Tags: api, authentication, espn

I'm a long time user of Mashery, but when I try to sign into the ESPN API I get the following message:

Login Failed
You must click on the link in your user confirmation email before you can login.

This seems easily solvable - however, I've never received a confirmation email.

Any help from the ESPN API staff would be greatly appreciated.

//MD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at this, but it's difficult to see which user account is yours without more information.  I do see one account in a "waiting" status, so I'll presume that is yours.  I do see another account using a gmail address that has the same first and last name as the one that is waiting to be confirmed.  The email address of the account waiting for confirmation is a .co account.

I don't see an option to resend the confirmation email, perhaps requesting a password reset on the login screen will help.  I'll see what else I can do, but try the reset first.

Comment: Now that I look more into this, I can't really figure out which account is yours without more information.  Searching on your name (as shown here) produced two results, but I'm not confident they are your accounts.

Comment: Hey Roger! Thanks for the quick response. My username is "atypical" - you can email me at mdavid@atypical.co - thank you for your help on this.

Comment: you should be all set now.